# How to get all the digits at the beginning of a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, digits

How can I get all the digits at the beginning of a string?

Here is an example string: `1&amp;days=800&amp;trans=9aq8ojjfka24qnl10ohktibfs1`

In the example above, I would need to extract `1`.

Comment: In such cases PHPs built-in type conversion is sufficient. `intval($str)` will return `1`.

Comment: What should be returned for no digits at the front of the string? What do you expect to be returned if the string starts with '000' for example? The comments on the answers show that you need to specify what you want a bit better please.

Comment: @vascowhite:  My question clearly mentioned I needed to get *all the digits* at the *beginning* of a string, so I'm not sure how I could have been any clearer.  Since `0` is a "digit", that includes leading 0's.

Comment: So if there are no digits, you expect an empty string?

Comment: BTW, I was attempting to help you solve your problem, I don't intend to seem antagonistic, apologies if I do.

Comment: @vascowhite:  No need to apologize, you actually generated a very interesting discussion with your solution, and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the leading digits - including mulitple zeros - you can [scan the string](http://php.net/sscanf) for it. If none exists, the value will be `NULL`:

```
$subject = '1&amp;days=800&amp;trans=9aq8ojjfka24qnl10ohktibfs1';   

sscanf($subject, '%[0-9]', $leadingDigits);

echo 'Leading digits are: ', var_dump($leadingDigits);
```

Outpupt ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JIlGuQ)):

```
Leading digits are: string(1) "1"
```

If you do not need leading zeroes, [do what vascowhite suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113062/367456), that is pretty straight forward. Otherwise:

```
sscanf($subject, '%d', $leadingDigits);
```

Returns an integer, too.

Comment: Thanks for another solution.  Curious, why do you suggest using `sscanf` over `preg_match`?

Comment: Because it's smaller, compare: `$leadingDigits = preg_match('(^\d+)', $subject, $matches) ? $matches[0] : '';`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I accepted your solution as it answered my question most efficiently.

Comment: @traxn: That's fine too, especially since the NULL value can be successfully compared to an empty string `''`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eLXQTC

Comment: @traxn:  Thanks for pointing that out, as I think it might be a deciding factor for others looking at this solution in the future, but for my purposes, NULL is fine.

Comment: It's written in the answer, that it will be `NULL`. However that is only correct if it has not been set earlier. If you initialize `$leadingDigits` to an empty string, it will not be changed if there is no match with `sscanf`. Just some more details for those who are interested ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match('(^\d+)', $str, $matches);
echo 'Leading digits are: ' . (count($matches) ? $matches[0] : '');
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a catch-all for digits without having to specify [0-9]?  If so, could you please also provide a solution that includes that catch-all?  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't seem to work:  http://codepad.viper-7.com/ObtEXk  Any ideas why?

Comment: @traxn What do expect to see returned if there is no number at the start of the string, you didn't specify that in your q.

Answer (score 4):

If the numbers are always at the start of the string, you can just cast to an int and PHP will take care of the rest.

```
var_dump((int)'1&amp;days=800&amp;trans=9aq8ojjfka24qnl10ohktibfs1');
```

Output:-

```
int 1
```

Will demonstrate my point. As will

```
var_dump((int)'7891&amp;days=800&amp;trans=9aq8ojjfka24qnl10ohktibfs1');
```

Output:-

```
int 7891
```

To make use of this:-

```
$myInt = (int)'1&amp;days=800&amp;trans=9aq8ojjfka24qnl10ohktibfs1';
```

See it working here http://codepad.viper-7.com/aih2x3

If you need leading zeros then you should [do what Hakre suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113315/212940). I think it's pretty future proof ;)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: I need this in a very important application, and my fear with your solution is what happens if future versions of PHP treat such type casting differently (e.g. a string with any text as "0", rather than the leading digits)?  I need the most future-proof solution, so how do you think that applies to your solution?

Comment: I don't really (want to) know what PHP will do in the future, but the regular expression solution allows you to check for the length of the leading digits, which can be 0 ("no digits").

Comment: I don't understand your concern This kind of type casting has been a part of PHP for a long time and as far as I am aware, there are no plans to depreciate it. It is fast, simple and safe, I honestly don't see a problem with it. I use this in my own apps and I am as keen as you are that they are as future proof as possible.

Comment: Not really working for all cases though, leading zeros are ignored.

Comment: @memowe To make it even more clear, this is the kind of type casting used internally by PHP itself. This is also the solution of PHP on the subject 'type-casting', to maintain the language dynamic touch. Secondly, if major/minor version of PHP are being released, you as a _developer_ have to maintain your code so that in future migration processes, your code still runs. On the other hand, you can also choose to use the version released 10 years ago, in the fear of being forced to changed your code ..

Comment: @dbf "How can I get all the digits at the beginning of a string?" does not mention integers.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson type-casting 0001 with `(int)0001` and the result is `1` means it is clearly working, keeping the leading zeros just means this might not be the optimal solution.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Well spotted, I'd missed that. Maybe the OP can clarify what he wants.

Comment: @vascowhite: My question clearly mentioned I needed to get "**all** the digits" at the "beginning" of a string, so I'm not sure how I could have been any clearer. Since 0 is a "digit", that includes leading 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP builtin FAST function
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php

```
// int strspn ( string $subject , string $mask [, ...])

$digits=substr($str,0,strspn($str,'0123456789')-1);
```